# What did Tarzan say to Cheeta when Cheeta did a good job?

Tags: dialogue, tarzan-1966

I am a native Korean speaker and I grew up watching the famous series "Tarzan", which was broadcast on TV with Korean dubbing. At times Cheeta did something clever in solving a problem and Tarzan used to say something like "Good job Cheeta". This "Good job Cheeta" became popular and viral among students and we used to say the same thing when someone did a good job both complementing and ridiculing the person. I am curious what Tarzan really said to Cheeta in that occasion in English. What did he say? "Well done, Cheeta" or "Good job, Cheeta" or something else?

Comment: I think "sequel"="serial" which probably refers to the B&W TV series circa 1965. (Or was it my TV that was B&W? :) )

Comment: @Paulie_D  The one I saw seems to be The New Advantures of Tarzan.